# Trying to ID the SMS delivery confirmation

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, smsmanager

I am currently trying to get the confirmation for each sended SMS. I need to be sure that my SMS are send, so I used a `BroadCastReceived` to get the information :

```
Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SMS_SEND);
    sentIntent.putExtra("key", idSms);
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, sentIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    try{
        manager.sendTextMessage(exp, null, sms, sentPI, null);
        put("sending " + sms); //Just a method to print in a textview use has a console
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        put("Exception " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

and use a broadcast receiver like this

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        String idsms = intent.getExtras().getString("key");

        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                put("ACK : #" + idsms);

                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                put("BOOM " + getResultCode() + "\n\tfrom sms #" + idsms);
                break;
        }
    }
```

This work like a charm until I try to send multiple messages at the same time, the extra receive is always from the last SMS send, so I can't ID which text are send and which are not.

Here is a simple example of what will happen.

When I use a loop to send 3sms:

> id : 1, message : SMS 1
>   id : 2, message : SMS 2
>   id : 3, message : SMS 3

And the received will get:

> ACK : #3
>   ACK : #3
>   ACK : #3

I understand that this come from the PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT but I can't find a solution. Anyone can explain to me how I should use the PendingIntent.getBroadcast(..) to be able to manage this or at least to put me on the right track.

Comment: For any futur downvoter, please explain what is the problem. This question is correctly written for me, even if I did this when I only had some reputation... For anyone, don't hesitate to ask for more information, I am pretty active here (depends on the work I have). So I can always reduce this example to something more [mcve] (this is clearly not ;) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is due the fact that `PendingIntent`s can be reused by the system, if certain things about the requests are not different. In your code, you're passing `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, which is causing the stored `Intent` and its extras to be updated each time a `PendingIntent` is requested. This is why you're getting `id : 3` for each of the messages. To correct this, you can call `getBroadcast()` with a unique request code (the second parameter) each time, which will create a new `PendingIntent` for each request, each with a separate `Intent` with their own extras.

In your case, the fix should be simple, assuming that `idSms` is unique for each message.

```
PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),
                                                  Integer.parseInt(idSms),
                                                  sentIntent,
                                                  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Yeah, tricky but really effective. About that, if I use a FLAG_ONE_SHOT (since I don't need it after I check the resultCode), is there a risk that the system use the same id (and then overrride my PendingIntent) or it is restricted to the context of the application?

Comment: @AxelH Yeah, that second one. PendingIntents are created by and for your app, so there's really no way the system or another app could create one that conflicts with yours.